# CSS place two divs with relative width next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#canvas {
    width: 80%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#chat {
    width: 15%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

There are a lot of questions about that here but its always solved with an absolute px width. Is there a way to place these two divs next to each other?
I dont want to give a specific width cause I want it to look good on different screens.

edit:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="canvas">

        <div>
        <div id="chat">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the html too please. Also, you have 3 id's so there must be 3 divs/elements.

Comment: which `div`s you want to be side by side, please state their `id`s

Comment: currently I see they are overlapping each other http://jsfiddle.net/7cc8rgqp/ why it's so?

Comment: Yes this is what I see in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this css rule:

```
#content > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Another way is to set property display `inline-block` to `#content` childs, like this:

```
#content > div {
     display: inline-block;
}
```

The answer is still right. You have a typo in your html, you have not closed `canvas` div properly. You have put `<div>` instead `</div>`.

Try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gb5x9na7/2/)

Comment: Its not working for me. In browser it looks like it sets the width to zero

Comment: I see that the fiddle works but as I said, when I try it in browser there is just a black line(the borders) on the left side of the screen. s.o. knows why?

Comment: O the </div> was the problem. Its working now. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline style or a float.

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

#canvas,
#chat {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#canvas {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#chat {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: same here. The divs look like having no width. If I add a relative width they are behind each other

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than 2 divs.
Just assign width property and float: left;

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="inner">Left</div>
 <div class="inner">Middle</div>
 <div class="inner">Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    width: 600px; /*width of outer box */
}

.inner {
    float: left; width: 100px; /* Width of each box */
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/_pirateX/yxL3fg16/

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no need to think about for width and you don't need to declare many css if you use the bootstrap class. For Example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div style="background-color:#0e0e0e;">column-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div style="background-color:#ff0000;">column-2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is it what you mean?**

Comment: Yes that is what I want to achieve, though they dont need to stack for small window sizes. I would prefer to do it without bootstrap